# Type inference only works for extension function

Tags: kotlin

The following code works fine and the call to the `foo.get()` extension function returns the correct type BarImpl.

```
open class Bar
class BarImpl: Bar()

class Foo<T : Bar> 

inline fun <reified T : Bar> Foo<T>.get(): T {
    return SomeMap(this).get(T::class)
}

class Activity {
    lateinit var foo: Foo<BarImpl>
    val barImpl = foo.get()
}
```

But when I try to move `Foo<T>.get()` into the class the type inference fails

```
class Foo<T : Bar> {
    inline fun <reified T : Bar> get(): T {
        return SomeMap(this).get(T::class)
    }
}

class Activity {
    lateinit var foo: Foo<BarImpl>
    val barImpl = foo.get()
}
```

> error: type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in inline fun  get(): T
>   Please specify it explicitly.
>
> ```
>    val vm = foo.get()
>                 ^
> ```

How can I move the function into the class?

Answer (score 4):

The extension function returns the result of the `Foo` type parameter. So the result type can be inferred from the receiver type.

And the member function result type has nothing in common with `Foo` type parameter except the name, which means nothing for a compiler. You can see that `T` in method and `T` in class are different types by writing and compiling the following code:

```
Foo<BarImpl>().get<BarImpl2>()
```

If you want to make `get` to be a member function which returns the result of `Foo` type parameter, you should remove type parameter from function and inject class instance via the constructor:

```
class Foo<T : Bar>(private val clazz: KClass<T>) {
    fun get(): T {
        return SomeMap(this).get(clazz)
    }

    companion object {
        inline operator fun <reified T : Bar> invoke() = Foo(T::class)
    }
}
```